# cannot import name format_html_join

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) shows the use of the following import

```
from django.utils.html import format_html_join
```

However, this import cannot be resolved.

Has it changed its name? or moved? Where can I find it now?

PS I'm using Django 1.4.5 (current stable version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only present in Django documentation 1.5, what version of Django do you have?

```
>>> import django
>>> print django.VERSION
```

Comment: 1.4, since when I'm I reading the 1.5 docs. that version is not out yet right?

Comment: is there something in 1.4 that will do the same?

Comment: look at the code ;p  seems easy to reproduce: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L88

Comment: dam, yep I see. did not know I was reading the out of date docs tho. :0 thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the documentation for the development version of django. It's likely that you don't have the development version installed on your machine (the current stable version is django 1.4.5 which doesn't include the function).

Here's a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) to the 1.4 version of the docs.